# How do I increment cell value in a formula in Excel

Tags: excel, google-maps, excel-formula

I am trying to put a formula in my Excel which is web service formula that will print out the XML of the map and then I will use filterout for the longitude and latitude. The file has 1736 records so is there a way I can apply the web service formula and it could change the cell value accordingly in the formula.

Formula is

```
=WEBSERVICE("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=c3+,+&sensor=false")
```

I want to change "c3" to c4, c5.... auto increment the value row by row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the URL in quotes and use `&` to add in `C3` reference.

```
=WEBSERVICE("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address="&C3&"+,+&sensor=false")
```

and drag down.

Comment: It increases the value but shows zero result as it takes & address &

Comment: Can you post some sample data, how you have it in your worksheet? What do you mean it takes "& address &"?  If I put `1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500` in `C3`, I get a result without errors.